# how to connect a docker compose application using django to a private AWS RDS postgres database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, docker

How can I connect my Django application to a private AWS Postgres RDS?

My current VPC infrastructure is setup like below:

- Two Public subnets
- Two Private subnets connected to a NAT Gateway. (NAT is linked to Public subnets)
- Postgres RDS database is connected to private subnets above

Please note that `docker-compose` is being used because i am using ECS Fargate for the backend infrastructure.

Currently my docker compose file is fine and django settings.py

## settings.py

(the env variable values are in the hidden `.env` file)

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": config("POSTGRES_DB", "postgres"),
        "USER": config("POSTGRES_USER", "postgres"),
        "PASSWORD": config("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "postgres"),
        "HOST": config("POSTGRES_HOST", "db"),
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

I have also updated the security groups of the database to allow necesary traffic and IAM Role.

The error from the logs that i am getting after spinning up `docker-compose up -d --build` then `docker-compose logs` is:

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name XXX.rds.amazonaws.com to address: Name or service not known`

I been stuck for days now and cant seem to find the solution, I would really appreciated if someone could help me figure it out.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error you are getting? You just have to give the django application the connection string of the RDS instance, and make sure the security group of the RDS instance allows the django application to connect.

Comment: @MarkB please find the error above, i have updated the post. i can make it work no problem with a public rds instance, but when it comes to private rds(public subnet + private subnets) it does not work and i am lost

Comment: Your running this code form ECS Fargate, not locally correct? You can't connect to a private RDS instance when you run `docker-compose up` locally, as it's private, so it's not available to you on your local computer, it's only available to software running inside the VPC.

Comment: @MarkB I see, I see..thank you for explaining plain and simple. I should just push the image of my app to ECR that handle everything inside the VPC from ECS Fargate, ok. I was indeed trying to connect local django to my VPC AWS RDS and expected it to work. I read only that using a bastion in the public subnet, i could ssh there then access the private rds instance...do you have any opinion about it? (thank you for your time)

Comment: Yes using a bastion for SSH port forwarding is one of the methods to connect to a private database from outside the VPC.